# What is the significance of "patients zero" in infectious disease beyond epidemiology?

Tags: infection, bacteria, virus, infectious-diseases

A common focus of press releases following outbreak of a "new" infectious disease is the "patient zero", or first individual to show infection. Why?

I can understand how epidemiologically it would be quite important to know where an infectious disease started and when to understand its spread, but is this information actually useful for development of treatments and vaccines?